# What is the idiomatic way to write pandas groupby result to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Source df as like:

```
EventType User Item
View        A     1    
View        B     1
Like        C     2
View        C     2
Buy         A     1
```

We have 5 users:  A B C D E

We have 6 Items:  1 2 3 4 5 6

I would like to generate new df like

```
Event_Type Event_Ratio    ItemsHaveEvent  UsersHaveEvent
View           0.6            0.33         0.6
Like           0.2            0.167        0.2
Buy            0.2            0.167        0.2
```

Event_Type:  same as EventType in original df

Event_Ratio:  the event / total events

ItemsHaveEvent:  items have this event / total items

UsersHaveEvent:  users have this event / total users

How to write idiomatic pandas code in declarative way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is with `named aggregation`:

```py
total_items = 6
total_users = 5
total_events = len(df)

(df
.groupby('EventType', sort = False, as_index = False)
.agg(
    EventRatio = ('EventType', lambda f: f.size/total_events),
     ItemsHaveEvent = ('Item', lambda f: f.nunique()/total_items),
     UsersHaveEvent = ('User', lambda f: f.nunique()/total_users))
)

  EventType  EventRatio  ItemsHaveEvent  UsersHaveEvent
0      View         0.6        0.333333             0.6
1      Like         0.2        0.166667             0.2
2       Buy         0.2        0.166667             0.2
```

Comment: Elegant and neat! One more question,  how to align all column names in one row? (EventType is visually lower than other column names)